# What is the meaning of `s attribute on a table?

Tags: kdb, k

In the *Abridged Q Language Manual* Arthur [mentioned](https://legaldocumentation.kx.com/q/d/a/q.htm#Attributes):

```
`s#table marks the table to use binary search and marks first column sorted
```

And if we look into 3.6 version:

```
N:1000000;
t1:t2:([]n:til N; m:N?`6);
t1:update `p#n from t1;
t2:`s#t2;
(meta t1)[`n]`a / `p
(meta t2)[`n]`a / `p
attr t1 / `
attr t2 / `s

\ts:10000 select count i from t1 where n in 1000?N
/ ~7000
\ts:10000 select count i from t2 where n in 1000?N
/ ~7000
```

we find that yes, `t2` has this attribute: `s`.

But for some reason an attribute on the first column is not `s` but `p`. And also search times are the same. And the sizes of both tables **with** attributes are the same - I used *objsize* function described in AquaQ [blogpost](https://www.aquaq.co.uk/q/adventure-in-retrieving-memory-size-of-kdb-object/) to ensure.

So are there any differences in 3.6+ version of `q` between `'s#table` and a `table` with `'#p` attribute on a first column?

Comment: "And the sizes of both tables with attributes are the same" not quite sure which attribute you are referencing, but `s# has no overhead as there is no additional structure to maintain for a sorted list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way that the s# on the table itself would improve search times is if you were doing lookups using `?` as described here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/find/#searching-tables

```
q)\ts:100000 t1?t1[0]
105 800
q)\ts:100000 t2?t2[0]
86 800
q)
q)\ts:100000 t1?t1[500000]
108 800
q)\ts:100000 t2?t2[500000]
83 800
q)
q)\ts:100000 t1?t1[999999]
107 800
q)\ts:100000 t2?t2[999999]
83 800
```

It behaves differently for a keyed table (turns it into a step function) but I think that's beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: Got it - one hypostasis of table is a list of dictionaries, so applying an attribute to the list makes faster searching through it (binary search).